# How to use href correcly with Angular routing?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-routing

Here, how I have configured the routing

```
var config = function (rp) {
    rp.when(
        '/docs',
        {
            templateUrl: 'Docs.htm'
        }
    );
};
config.$inject = ['$routeProvider'];
app.config(config);
```

then I added

```
<a href="#docs">Docs</a>
```

to my htm page.

when the link is clicked, URL is changed to

> my_pagename.htm#!#docs

and it does not load the template.

but when I manually type the URL in location as

> my_pagename.htm#!/docs (replaced hash symbol with '/')

it loads fine.

Can you please tell me the error here?

what is the proper way of specifying the href attribute, in order to work with angular routing?
My angular version is 1.6.3

Comment: can you make a fiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know the consequences, but I changed the hrefs to

```
    #!/<link>

Ex: #!/docs
    #!/contacts
```

and now they work fine.

**note that I didn't change route paths in js file.**

Answer (score 0):

Why did you add # with href

try this

```
<a href="docs">Docs</a>
```

Comment: that way it goes to another page.

Comment: @ddarz4u it would do if the router didn't intercept the request and do it's thing.